# How to access returned function values from another function

Tags: python, function, return-value

I wanted to access the returned function values from another function, but I couldn't succeed on it. Can someone show me how to do ?

Here is the defined function 'thermo' and Im using IAPWS97 library

```
def thermo (p = 0.006112127, H = 1493):
    tp = IAPWS97(P= p, h= H )
    rho = tp.rho
    temp = tp.T
    xq = tp.x
    tpmu = IAPWS97(T=temp, x= 0) 
    Mu = tpmu.mu
    return rho,temp,xq,Mu
```

and this is the second  function

```
def f2 (m= 1, g= 2, h= 3):
    c = m*g+h
    rho_p = -rho / p^c
    return rho_p
```

[image: here is the error]

Thank you

Comment: To compute `rho_p`, you need to **call** your function `thermo()` at some point. Probably from within `f2()`. Can you show us the rest of the code?

Comment: Read about scopes of variables in Python. You get the error because the function `f2` has no clue what `rho` is, because it was defined in and returned from `thermo`. You're going to have to call `thermo` inside `f2` and use the returned value from that, or define `rho` at a level higher than `f2`, or pass `rho` to `f2`.

Comment: Are you aware that there is no *single* returned value of a function, but a new one everytime the function finishes? Did you actually call ``thermo``, and what did you do with the return value of that call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define these functions, you are writing down how to compute output values based on provided input values. In order to get the output value for a function, you need to **call** the function, like this:

```py
def f2(m=1, g=2, h=3):
    c = m * g + h
    rho, temp, xq, Mu = thermo(p, h)
    rho_p = -rho / p ^ c
    return rho_p
```

Unfortunately, even the code I gave you above won't work. You'll get `NameError: name 'p' is not defined`, because you haven't specified what the value of the variable `p` is. I inferred that you might use `h` as the input value for `H` in `thermo`, but that was just a guess. When you call a function, you need to provide it with all the inputs it needs. If you don't have a value, you either need to create it explicitly (like `thermo(0.0112, h)`) or make the caller of `f2` provide it (like `def f2(m=1, g=2, h=3, p=0.0112)`).

It sounds like you might need to spend some time reading about how to define and use functions. Here's the official Python tutorial's section on [defining functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: I am so grateful for your advice, finally realized the missing point. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the first function and store the output value for rho and feed that into the f2 function.

```
def f2 (m, g2, h3, rho):
    c = m*g+h
    rho_p = -rho / p^c
    return rho_p

def thermo (p = 0.006112127, H = 1493):
    tp = IAPWS97(P= p, h= H )
    rho = tp.rho
    temp = tp.T
    xq = tp.x
    tpmu = IAPWS97(T=temp, x= 0) 
    Mu = tpmu.mu
    return rho,temp,xq,Mu

a,b,c,d = thermo(p = 0.006112127, H = 1493)

f2(1,2,3,a)
```